# Sorting dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

Consider the following dataset:

```
seq_id  a  b  id 

1       20 13 1
2       21 14 1
3       18 19 1
1       22 15 2
2       21 14 2
1       25 12 1
2       27 13 1
```

I need to sort my data set by id , however I have more than one group for the specific id. for example there are 2 groups of id 1. 
I need the following result:

```
seq_id  a  b  id 

1       20 13  1
2       21 14  1
3       18 19  1
1       25 12  1
2       27 13  1
1       22 15  2
2       21 14  2
```

I tried this script which is not correct:

```
sort = lambda x: sorted(x,reverse=False)
data = data.sort_values(by=['id'],ascending=True)
data.groupby('id').seq_id.apply(sort)
```

thanks for your comments.

Or is there any way to change the second group's name of id = 1 to separate them from each other. for example lets say, for the first group id = 1 and for the second group id = 1-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
data = data.sort_values(by=['id'], ascending=True, kind='mergesort')
```

Adding `kind='mergesort'` switches the `sort_values` call to use a "stable" sorting algorithm (see [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)), which means that the original order of rows will be preserved for rows that have an equal value for the sorting criterion.